# Focus object “.” Issue

Tags: selection-tools

I’ve started learning Blender 2.8 this week and I can’t seem to focus on object with the numpad shortcut <kbd>.</kbd>

When I have object in my viewport that I can see, selecting them and using the shortcut will frame up on the object just fine, it’s when I drag away in to no mans land and can not see my object in the viewport were I’m having my issue.

Selecting the objects in the object manager and using the shortcut doesn’t work as it does in the tutorials I am learning from. Sometimes when I select objects in the manager they will have read text but mostly it’s orange.

To reiterate, I can’t  frame up on objects once out of my viewport and selecting them on the object manger does nothing either.

Any help would be appreciated as it’s a useful shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the mouse back into the *3D Viewport*. Since each *Editor* has their own respective keyboard shortcuts, Blender will pass the keyboard commands to the *Editor* your mouse is hovering over. So select the object in the *Outliner*, move your mouse back over to the *3D Viewport*, and press <kbd>.</kbd>.

Comment: :) thank you very much!